# Python to C++: Algorithm that list all combinations of Knapsack using recursion

Tags: python, c++, algorithm, recursion, knapsack-problem

I'm trying to implement a code that lists all possible combinations of a Knapsack problem using recursion. I have difficulty with recursion. I tried to solve it and got nothing, so I did some research and I found a code in <strike>Java</strike> Python, but I'm having a hard time trying to rewrite that code in C++.

Here is the solution code, in <strike>Java</strike> Python:

```
items = [1,1,3,4,5]
knapsack = []
limit = 7

def print_solutions(current_item, knapsack, current_sum):
    #if all items have been processed print the solution and return:
    if current_item == len(items):
        print knapsack
        return

    #don't take the current item and go check others
    print_solutions(current_item + 1, list(knapsack), current_sum)

    #take the current item if the value doesn't exceed the limit
    if (current_sum + items[current_item] <= limit):
        knapsack.append(items[current_item])
        current_sum += items[current_item]
        #current item taken go check others
        print_solutions(current_item + 1, knapsack, current_sum )

print_solutions(0,knapsack,0)
```

I found that code in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30007102/number-of-all-combinations-in-knapsack-task)

Here is what I tried to do..

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;   

void AddItem(int item, int *knapsack) {
    int i = 0;
    while (knapsack[i] != -1)
        i++;    
    knapsack[i] = item;

};
void printKnapsack(int *knapsack, int n) {
    cout << "[";
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        if (knapsack[i] != -1)
            cout << knapsack[i] << ",";
}

void print_solutions(int current_item, int *knapsack, int current_sum, int *items, int n, int limit) {
    //if all items have been processed print the solution and return
    if (current_item == n - 1) {
        printKnapsack(knapsack, n);
        return;
    };

    //don't take the current item and go check others
    print_solutions(current_item + 1, knapsack, current_sum, items, n, limit);

    //take the current item if the value doesn't exceed the limit
    if (current_sum + items[current_item] <= limit) {
        AddItem(items[current_item], knapsack);
        current_sum += items[current_item];
    };
    //current item taken go check others
    print_solutions(current_item + 1, knapsack, current_sum, items, n, limit);

};

int main() {
    int current_item = 0;
    int current_sum = 0;
    int limit, n;
    cout << "Type the maximum weight ";
    cin >> limit;
    cout << "How many items?  ";
    cin >> n;
    int* knapsack;
    knapsack = new int[10];
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        knapsack[i] = -1;
    int * items;
    items = new int[n];

    cout << "Type weights.";
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        cin >> items[i];
    };

    print_solutions(0, knapsack, 0, items, n, limit);

    return 0;

}
```

With the input:

```
7                       // limit
5                       // number of items 
1 1 3 4 5               // items
```

I expect to get the following final result:

```
[]
[5]
[4]
[3]
[3, 4]
[1]
[1, 5]
[1, 4]
[1, 3]
[1]
[1, 5]
[1, 4]
[1, 3]
[1, 1]
[1, 1, 5]
[1, 1, 4]
[1, 1, 3]
```

But all I get is arrays filled with 3 and 4 instead of getting all actual solutions.

Comment: Thats not java, thats python

Comment: Oh sorry! I fixed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### In short

There is a major issue in your transcription of the algorithm from python to C++ related to the language semantics related to parameter passing.

#### In full details

When in python you write the following:

```
    print_solutions(current_item + 1, list(knapsack), current_sum)
```

Then `list(knapsack)` is a [copy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2322079/3723423) from the `knapsack` list.  So the recursive call in the middle leaves the original `knapsack` unchanged, whereas the second recursive call changes the original `knapsack`:

```
print_solutions(current_item + 1, knapsack, current_sum)
```

In your C++ code however, in both case you work on the original `knapsack` list (the arrays parameters are passed by references), so that `knapsack` gets completely messed up:

```
//don't take the current item and go check others
print_solutions(current_item + 1, knapsack, current_sum, items, n, limit);
```

### How to make it work ?

Either you create a temporary array and copy `knapsack` in it, or, much better, you start to use `vector` , which will make your C++ life much easier (making attention to pass by value or by reference).

The following version uses a vectors.  The `&` in the parameter means that it's an argument passed by reference (i.e. the original vector can be changed).  Note that we do no longer need to pass `n`, as the vector knows its length, as list do in python:

```
void print_solutions(int current_item, vector<int>& knapsack, int current_sum, const vector<int>& items, int limit) {  

    //if all items have been processed print the solution and return
    if (current_item == items.size() ) {
        printKnapsack(knapsack);
        return;
    };

    //don't take the current item and go check others
    vector<int> knapcopy = knapsack; 
    print_solutions(current_item + 1, knapcopy, current_sum, items, limit);

    //take the current item if the value doesn't exceed the limit
    if (current_sum + items[current_item] <= limit) {
        knapsack.push_back(items[current_item]);
        current_sum += items[current_item];
        //current item taken go check others
        print_solutions(current_item + 1, knapsack, current_sum, items, limit);
    };
};
```

Here an [online demo](https://ideone.com/CwUANx).

Comment: Thank you so much! Once you suggested using vectors, I studied a bit of it and I was trying to make it work. I'm happy seeing your code now: I was quite close!